# pulling data from a sql table that stores price history

Tags: sql

I have been trying to figure out how to pull data out of sql table that holds the history of price changes for items in inventory.  Example of how the data is laid out is below:

```
Item No   Date changed   Price
1         11/20/2012     15
2         11/28/2012     25
1         12/1/2012      18
```

I am needing to pull the last entry for each item no so that i can find where prices have change by more than a certain percent.  Once I get the information all worked out but i am not sure how to pull only the last two updates for each item.  Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: what version of sql server are you using, MS SQL? MySQL? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got it to work. 
create table ##inventoryitems (ID INT Identity(1,1),itemno char(11));

insert into ##inventoryitems
select distinct itemno
from InventoryActPkgCostHist
where LocID=3

create table ##temptable (item# char(11),changedate datetime,price numeric(8,2));

DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 1
while @Counter<=(select COUNT(*) from ##inventoryitems)

begin
insert into ##temptable
select top 2 i.itemno,i.ActPkgCostDate,i.ActPkgCost
from InventoryActPkgCostHist i join ##inventoryitesm temp on i.itemno= temp.itemno
where temp.id=@Counter and locidd=3
order by itemno,ActPkgCostDate desc

set @Counter=@Counter+1

end

Thank you for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

Simple order it by date and retrieve exactly two rows per id.

`SELECT Price FROM table WHERE id=2 ORDER BY date_changed DESC LIMIT 0,2`

This are the two last price changes.

Comment: This will work, but requires looping over item numbers, if he's doing this for every item, that might be a problem